# Azure Powershell Diagnostics Settings

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

What would be the correct sequence to enable diagnostic settings for a resource in Azure?

I was trying `Set-AzureRMDiagnosticSettings` in **Powershell 5.0** to enable the settings on an MSSQL Paas database. But it doesn't seem to be working.

I am using the OMS workspace for diagnostic Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the command below, it works fine on my side. It enable `Diagnostic settings` in azure sql database and pass the same to OMS workspace.

```
$workspaceName = '<OMSworkspaceName>'
$ResourceGroupName = '<ResourceGroupName>'
$oms=Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $workspaceName
$WSID = $oms.ResourceId
$resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases -ResourceName "<sqlservername>/<databasename>"
$resourceId = $resource.ResourceId  
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resourceId -WorkspaceId $WSID -Enable $True
```

[image]
 [image]

Check in the portal:

[image]